# total probability theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

The problem is defined as: We got a machine part that can be produced in series of 20 . 3 Machines produce that part. Some of the parts way be invalid.

The First machine produced 15 out of 20 valid parts.

The Second machine produced 18 out of 20 valid parts.

The Third machine produced 16 out of 20 valid parts.

Randomly a series of products is chosen ( I , II, III ) and a part is taken out. The part that's taken out its valid. The same part it's returned into the series that it has came from and a draw for one more part is done from the chosen series. What's the probability that in the second draw the part that's taken out its a valid part?

I got tried to solve this problem. Here is what I've got so far:

**Hypothesis:**

*A- A valid part is chosen*

*H1- We draw from first series*

*H2- We draw from second series*

*H3- We draw from third series*

*P(H1)=P(H2)=P(H3)=1/3*

*P(A|H1)=15/20*

*P(A|H2)=18/20*

*P(A|H3)=16/20*

**P(A)= P(H1)*P(A|H1)+P(H2)*P(A|H2)+P(H3)*P(A|H3)***

Is this the way to solve this problem or I am missing something?

Comment: That is the probability that a drawn part is valid.  But here you have drawn two parts from the same series and the first part was seen to be valid

Comment: There are twenty parts in the series, you took one out and *returned* it knowing it is valid. From this you can determine the conditional probability distribution for source knowing at least one part was valid, which tells you the probability that any *other* part in the same series is valid, but don't forget the possibility that you may draw the exact same part again.

Comment: IE: remember, you are drawing *with* replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_1, A_2$ represent the events for the two parts drawn being valid, when drawn *with* replacement from a series of 20 items produced by one of three machines.   Let $H_{\rm I},H_{\rm II},H_{\rm III}$ be the event that the series originates in the respective machine.

Given that the first sample drawn was valid, updating the probability for the series originating from factory#$\rm I$ is an application for Bayes' Rule.

$$\mathsf P(H_{\rm I}\mid A_1) ~{= \dfrac{\mathsf P(A_1\mid H_{\rm I})\mathsf P(H_{\rm I})}{\mathsf P(A_1\mid H_{\rm I})\mathsf P(H_{\rm I})+\mathsf P(A_1\mid H_{\rm II})\mathsf P(H_{\rm II})+\mathsf P(A_1\mid H_{\rm III})\mathsf P(H_{\rm III})} \\ = \dfrac {15}{15+18+16}\quad=\dfrac{15}{49}}$$

Because when drawing with replacement from the series there is $1/20$ probability for picking the known valid part, and a $19/20$ probability for drawing another part from $H_{\rm I}$ (which are valid with probability $15/20$).

$$\mathsf P(A_2\mid H_{\rm I}, A_1) =\dfrac 1{20}+\dfrac{19}{20}\dfrac{15}{20}$$

And so forth for the other factories.   *Now* apply the law of total (conditional) probability:

$$\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1)~=~ \sum\limits_{m\in\{{\rm I},{\rm II},{\rm III}\}}\mathsf P(A_2\mid H_m, A_1)\,\mathsf P(H_m\mid A_1)$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This makes a lot more sense. Last thing the P(A2|H1,A1) is a big confusing. Does the 1/20 come from the first draw? And afterwards we got 19/20 chances to pick anything else aka not the first known valid part?

Comment: @LexByte Yes. The precedent paragraph explained.  The probability that the next draw is valid, given the first was and they cam from machine $\rm I$ is: the probability for drawing the known valid sample *or* drawing one of the others and that one is valid.